# Error in Drag and Drop quiz done of Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a drag and drop game on flash. But i end up got one error, syntax error of #error1083,else is unexpected.
The error shows at the line 42, and i dont have any idea which line should i did mistake.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Here is the codes

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    var objectoriginalX:Number;
    var objectoriginalY:Number;

    blue.buttonMode = true;
    blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickObject);
    blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);




    green.buttonMode = true;
    green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickObject);
    green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);


    red.buttonMode = true;
    red.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickObject);
    red.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

    function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        event.target.startDrag();
        event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
        objectOriginalX = event.target.x;
        objectOriginalY = event.target.y;
    }

function dropObject (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = event.target.name + "target" ;
    var matchingTarget: DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);

    if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget);

{
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickupObject);
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropObject);
    event.target.buttonMode = false;
    event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
    event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
}



    else { // here is where i got error 1083
            event.target.x = objectOriginalX;
            event.target.y = objectOriginalY;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` at the end of the line:

```
if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget);
```

Comment: I did. But still got error. The errors are Access undenied of property objectOriginalX, objectOriginalY, and pickObject

Comment: Can you upload the FLA file?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually my mistake was the misspelled word. I've corrected them but I encountered another problem which I already told Joseph in the above statement.

Comment: I try the other way, i drag the answer into the target drop zone and click the next button, it moves to the next scene but the previous answer remain the same place which on the target drop zone. Help needed :(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding objectOriginalX and friends, the problem is that you are not initializing the variables.  Unlike `int`, which initializes to `0`, `Number` variables don't initialize to actual values, instead they are `NaN` (not-a-number).  You must set those values before you use them in calculation, as in...

```
var objectoriginalX:Number = 0;
var objectoriginalY:Number = 0;
```

...or set them to their starting points first.  Also, you might be trying to add pickObject before you've initialized it.  `Object` initializes to `null`, so you need to assign pickObject to something before it gets used.  For example, in this line...

```
blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickObject);
```

...does pickObject exist yet?  It must not be null; it must be assigned before you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now i can settle the error. Actually, I am quite dumb, the error was a very simple syntax error, which i misspelled. What a clumsy human.

Comment: But now, I've move on and encountered another problem. I want to put the next button on the drag and drop quiz which can guide user to the next scene or frame (if can). But it doesnt work. Everytime I click the next button, the correct answer will turn to the original back and the scene doesnt move to another. Can you help this beginner?